# Can BDD work for Big Data ETL testing?

Tags: testing, bigdata, bdd

I was wandering if anyone uses BDD for testing a Big Data ETL application?
I can see how BDD can be used for testing applications having a client interact with them, but in case of Big Data ETL application there is no client interaction so its hard to see what 'When' I might use. 
For example:
Give 100 event of type A occur
And 50 event of type B occur after 5 minute
Then database rows should be:
|Type|Count|Bucket|
|A|100|1|
|B|50|2|

But that seems wrong.
Any one with an insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give me an example of what you'd expect to see in an ETL output?

There are a couple of responses you could give to this. One might be the different kinds of database rows you'd expect, and the fact that some of them will probably be repeated, but not others. That was something that struck me as weird, but if you're used to working with star schemas then you'll probably notice other differences instead.

Normally I'd steer people away from talking about the database, but if you're working with star schemas, I think it's OK to mention the facts and dimensions (I haven't worked with ETL a lot, but I do remember talking through specific examples of these and what I would expect to see).

The alternative is to use the client.

I saw that you said there was no client; however, there's *always* a client, even if it's one that might exist in the future. There are implications for ETL which run across security, performance and access, amongst others. It's worth having a client, even if it's a string-based or SQL-based toy, to explore the things which might trip you up.

Why are you doing this? What's new about the thing the business or users or customers will be able to do when this is in place, that they can't do already? And can you get hold of an example of that?

"We'll be able to understand how X is performing against Y standard."

Great. Can you give me an example of some X, some Y, and some standard? How will you measure the performance? What data will you be looking for? Should everyone be able to see that data? Can you think of any scenario where someone shouldn't be able to access that?

Those examples become the ETL equivalent of scenarios; the conversations retain the same pattern. You just end up automating them at a different level, since your API is machine-oriented rather than human-oriented, and some of your conversations will be about monitoring instead of testing. Your conversations should still be with the people.

Your "when" will be the query or report that you run, within the data, permission and security context in which you run it.

Comment: Thats an interesting insight regarding the 'When', my question is: dont we make extra effort to fit to BDD? the behavior in such cases is so cumbersome that my sentences will be unreadable, I gave such a simple example that doesnt fit any ETL, since usually the ETL is about the exact structure of the data, The 'Given' might be a page describing the structure

Comment: I think people overthink BDD a lot of the time. Stick with the answer to, "Can you give me an example?" And whatever comes out will usually have the right language. Not everything is a good fit for natural language though - and star schemas aren't particularly intuitive! - so if your example is better suited to tables, then use tables. If it's only ever going to be read by technical people, rather than business, then it's OK to use code to describe these things too.

Comment: It seems to me that best approach will be splitting business behavior, using good day scenario (for data structure) from system testing (manipulating data structure for all edge cases). Then the system test can be reviewed if using BDD at all. My only fear is that the link between system test and business requirements will be lost.

Comment: There's always some new capability the business want. Ask, "What will we / our customers / our analysts / etc. be able to do once this is live that they can't do right now?" If the information contained in the ETL is the new thing, then knock up a toy client to it and write the scenarios over that. If the client is the new thing, and you're merely supporting that client, let the client devs drive out scenarios for that client and work with them to support it. A client might be an SQL report rather than a specific UI, but it will be something that someone uses. That will help you keep the link.

Answer (score 1):

BDD always works for application logic inside Big data space. Remember the testing triangle principle. Have your unit tests. Practice BDD and build your integration and acceptance tests with BDD and within your sprint. Its not recommended to have your test data externally maintained and thus validating E2E flow with all moving pieces needs to be light weight. Practice TDD model if permits.